# C++ Unable to write to virtual memory despite being marked as read & write

Tags: c++, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am unable to write to a virtual memory block despite it being flagged as PAGE_READWRITE. This is the exception thrown at runtime:

```
Exception thrown at 0x722E4AE9 (vcruntime140d.dll) in ConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char* memblock;

    memblock = new char[8] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    LPVOID virtual_memory_area = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 8, MEM_PHYSICAL, PAGE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(virtual_memory_area, memblock, 8);
}
```

Comment: The documentation says that when an error occurs it VirtualAlloc returns null and sets an error. Maybe this one helps you there.

Comment: Heed what Hayt says. I sincerely doubt `location 0x00000000` is read-write on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flAllocationType` parameter of `VirtualAlloc` must have one of `MEM_COMMIT`, `MEM_RESERVE`, `MEM_RESET` or `MEM_RESET_UNDO`. The `MEM_PHYSICAL` is optional flag for `flAllocationType`.

You have only `MEM_PHYSICAL`, hence `VirtualAlloc` fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error, you are trying to write to a null pointer hence the exception. The reason is that VirtualAlloc failed and returned null.